# Updating list of dictionaries with another list of dictionaries. Is there a faster way?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries that I need to update with information from another list of dictionaries. My current solution (below) works by taking every dictionary from the first list and comparing it to every dictionary in the second list. It works, but is there a faster, more elegant way of achieving the same result?

```
a = [ { "id": 1, "score":200 }, { "id": 2, "score":300 }, { "id":3, "score":400 } ]
b = [ { "id": 1, "newscore":500 }, { "id": 2, "newscore":600 } ]
# update a with data from b
for item in a:
    for replacement in b:
        if item["id"]==replacement["id"]:
            item.update({"score": replacement["newscore"]})
```

Comment: Are you open to using libraries like `pandas`?

Comment: Will the first element list of `a` alway have the same index as the matching element list element in `b`?

Comment: If you have a very large data set and need to do this, consider moving to a faster language like swift or rust or C. Python tries hard to make the obvious stuff fast. It's best to keep the python super readable, rather than have tricksy code that's a little faster, in an interpreter that many, many times slower than C.

Answer (score 3):

Create a dictionary indexed by `id` using the first array. 
Loop through the second array using the `id`.

```
for replacement in b:
   v = lookup.get(replacement['id'], None)
   if v is not None:
      v['score'] = replacement['newscore']
```

This converts an `O(n^2)` problem to an `O(n)` problem.

Comment: 1) I think your syntax is wrong -- it looks like you want to make a dictionary, but instead you're trying to make a set, which will fail.  2) It's not O(n log n); dictionaries are hashmaps with amortized O(1) lookup.

Comment: Probably wanted something like `{ x['id']: x for x in a }` to build a dict instead of a set of tuples.

Comment: Also probably meant to swap a and b, and `v = lookup['id']` will KeyError if the key is missing and never make it to the `if v is not None`.  This really needs a few tweaks before it's ready to use.

Comment: @DSM - yep, I've fixed that up now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a len(a) * len(b) loop, process b into something easier to work with:

```
In [48]: replace = {d["id"]: {"score": d["newscore"]} for d in b}

In [49]: new_a = [{**d, **replace.get(d['id'], {})} for d in a]

In [50]: new_a
Out[50]: [{'id': 1, 'score': 500}, {'id': 2, 'score': 600}, {'id': 3, 'score': 400}]
```

Note that the `{**somedict}` syntax requires a modern version of Python (>= 3.5.)

Answer (score 1):

**List Comprehension:**

```
[i.update({"score": x["newscore"]}) for x in b for i in a if i['id']==x['id']]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'score': 500}, {'id': 2, 'score': 600}, {'id': 3, 'score': 400}]
```

**Timing:**

```
%timeit [i.update({"score": x["newscore"]}) for x in b for i in a if i['id']==x['id']]
```

Output:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.9 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using `pandas` and a, b are pandas dataframes then here is a oneliner

```
a.loc[a.id.isin(b.id), 'score'] = b.loc[b.id.isin(a.id), 'newscore']
```

Converting a, b to dataframes is simple, just use `pd.DataFrame.from_records`

---

Another way of doing this if you can change "newscore" to "score"

```
a = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a, index="id")
b = pd.DataFrame.from_records(b, index="id")
a.update(b)
```

Here are the timeit results

```
In [10]: %timeit c = a.copy(); c.update(b)
702 µs ± 37.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a dict of scores to update:

```
>>> new_d={d['id']:d for d in b}
>>> new_d
{1: {'id': 1, 'newscore': 500}, 2: {'id': 2, 'newscore': 600}}
```

Then iterate over a and update by id:

```
for d in a:
    if d['id'] in new_d:
        d['score']=new_d[d['id']]['newscore']

>>> a
[{'id': 1, 'score': 500}, {'id': 2, 'score': 600}, {'id': 3, 'score': 400}]
```

Which could be even simpler as:

```
new_d={d['id']:d['newscore'] for d in b}
for d in a:
    if d['id'] in new_d:
        d['score']=new_d[d['id']]
```